# Suddenly, all text in terminal is corrupted

Tags: gnome-terminal, fonts

[image]

So, out of the blue today my terminal looks like this. Any idea? I just went through the regular updates. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. No issue on any other text field: it's just the terminal.

Comment: try `stty sane`

Comment: This is glyph cache corruption. Do you use Intel graphics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Terminal menu choose Edit->Profile Preferences and check the font choice as shown below:

[image: terminal-font]

By adjusting these settings you should be able to get back to "normal" output.

Comment: This is a useless answer. Ubuntu does not have a font where 50% of the characters are deliberately replaced by random graphical corruption. OP clearly has a buggy graphics driver, or a hardware problem.

Comment: @AlistairBuxton If I felt that way about an answer I wouldn't hesitate to write a better one  whether there was an accepted answer or not. I encourage you to do that.